# C++ Launch Program Separate From Existing Application

Tags: c++

How can I launch a program that is totally unconnected to my application?  In other words, how can I create another parent process, not a child process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Process relationships on Windows are *very* weak.  There is no `SIGCHLD`.  There is no detach-from-terminal necessary to avoid `SIGHUP` death.  Really, the parent process is only important insofar as a bunch of environment stuff can be automatically copied to the child.

You may want to look at starting the process in a new process group, or attached to a new job object.  See the [`CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684863(v=vs.85).aspx) flag.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to call the `system()` command. This can be found in `<cstdlib>` (aka `<stdlib.h>`).

Example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    // Open the Window's Calculator:
    system("C:/Windows/system32/calc.exe");
    return 0;
}
```

You can pass whatever command you would like as the `system()` parameter (assuming you have the permissions necessary to execute the command).

This also works for Linux/Unix systems.

---

**Edit:** before implementing calls to `system()`, you might want to check out [this write-up](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/j3wTURfi/) about it. Some people believe using `system()` is unsafe/a bad practice. However, for launching an unrelated program, I personally believe `system()` is a fine solution.

It is also good to make sure `system()` is available before calling it with your command. On some systems, you may not be allowed to spawn a shell/command-prompt. To check for this, you can do the following:

```
if( system(NULL) ){
    // spawning a shell is allowed
    system( commandToExecute );
    return 0;
}else{
    // spawning a shell is prohibited
    return ERROR_NO_SHELL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [_spawnv](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/7zt1y878(v=vs.80).aspx) and [_exec](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/431x4c1w(VS.80).aspx).

And if you're on Windows use [CreateProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx).